# HTML Doctype Causing Video Autoplay Without Scrolled to

Tags: javascript, html, video, autoplay

Basically, I want to autoplay the HTML5 video when I scrolled down to the video. By referring [this code](http://blog.wheelstudios.net/2009/09/how-to-autostart-a-html5-or-youtube-video-when-you-scroll-down/), I got the result I want.

My problem is the video is autoplay without scroll when I use `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration. I need to use `<html>` to solve it instead.

But when I removed the `<!DOCTYPE html>`, my other codes are affected. So I'm forced to use `<!DOCTYPE html>` :(

Can anyone suggest a solution to this issue? Use `<!DOCTYPE html>` without affecting the autoplay video when scrolled down. Sorry for my poor English.

```js
function inViewPort (elem) {
  //First get the scroll y position (how far the user scrolled down)
  var scrollY = document.body.scrollTop;
  //Now get the height of the viewport
  var screenH=document.body.clientHeight;
  //Also get the y position of the element
  var yPos=elem.offsetTop;
  //And now calculate the maximal y position for elem when it is still visible
  var maxY=scrollY+screenH;

  if (yPos>scrollY && yPos<maxY) {
    //It is in the users viewport
    return true;
  } else {
    //It isn't in the users viewport
    return false;
  }
}

function checkStart (videoName) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(videoName);
  if (inViewPort(elem)) {
    elem.load();
    elem.play();
  } else if (!elem.ended) {
    setTimeout("checkStart('"+videoName+"');", 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="checkStart('vid');">
    <div style="witdh: 100%; height: 1000px; background: #aaaaaa;">
      <h1>Scroll down to start the video</h1>
    </div>
    </p>
 
    <video src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" id="vid" width="500px" controls>
      Your browser doesn't support this video. Please upgrade your browser.
    </video>
</body>
```

Comment: Video tag is HTML5 feature , so you have to tell the browser with <!DOCTYPE html> that it contains html 5 elements .On page load you can pause the video with JS

Comment: How to pause the video with JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extend condition:

```
 if (yPos > scrollY && yPos < maxY && scrollY !=0 )
```

This will work when user scroll to particular video position

```js
function inViewPort (elem) {
  //First get the scroll y position (how far the user scrolled down)
  var scrollY = document.body.scrollTop;
  //Now get the height of the viewport
  var screenH=document.body.clientHeight;
  //Also get the y position of the element
  var yPos=elem.offsetTop;
  //And now calculate the maximal y position for elem when it is still visible
  var maxY=scrollY+screenH;

  if (yPos>scrollY && yPos<maxY && scrollY !=0) {
    //It is in the users viewport
    return true;
  } else {
    //It isn't in the users viewport
    return false;
  }
}

function checkStart (videoName) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(videoName);
  if (inViewPort(elem)) {
    elem.load();
    elem.play();
  } else if (!elem.ended) {
    setTimeout("checkStart('"+videoName+"');", 100);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="checkStart('vid');">
    <div style="witdh: 100%; height: 1000px; background: #aaaaaa;">
      <h1>Scroll down to start the video</h1>
    </div>
    </p>
 
    <video src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" id="vid" width="500px" controls>
      Your browser doesn't support this video. Please upgrade your browser.
    </video>
</body>
```

Comment: Cool ! Your answer solved my issue. Thank you so much. :)